# Http Status 500 returned on Spring MVC Using REST Templates and JSON Response Format

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

My Project Consist Of Four Tables as Following :

1. **Questions** - Question_id, Question Text
2. **User** - User_ID, Name
3. **Question_Answer** - UserID, Question_ID, Answer
4. **QuestionType** - QuestionID, Tag

I have to Generate questions based on Multiple Tags

Or Simply return List of all Questions (when no Tags are Provided)

Or insert answers Provided by The Users into The **Question_Answer** Table.

The Controller class **SpringServiceController.java** (generates result in JSON format)is as Follows :

```
package com.bargadss.SpringService.Controller;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.bargadss.SpringService.DAO.QuestionService;
import com.bargadss.SpringService.Domain.*;


@RestController

@RequestMapping("/service/question/")
public class SpringServiceController {
  QuestionService questionService=new QuestionService();

 @RequestMapping(value = "/{tag1},{tag2},{tag3}", method =  RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
 public List<Questions> getQuestions(@PathVariable("tag1") String tag1, @PathVariable("tag2") String tag2, @PathVariable("tag3") String tag3) {
  List<Questions> Qobj=questionService.getQuestionByTag(tag1, tag2, tag3);
  return Qobj;
 }

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
 public List<Questions> getAllQuestions() {  
  List<Questions> Qobj=questionService.getAllQuestion();
  return Qobj;   
 }

 @RequestMapping(value="/insert/{user_id}/{question_id}/{answer}",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
  public List<Questions> addQuestions(@PathVariable int user_id,@PathVariable int question_id,@PathVariable String answer) throws ParseException { 
      Question_Answer qtnAns = new Question_Answer();
      qtnAns.setUser_id(user_id);
      qtnAns.setQuestion_id(question_id);
      qtnAns.setAnswer(answer);
      questionService.insertAnswer(qtnAns.getUser_id(), qtnAns.getQuestion_id(), qtnAns.getAnswer());
      return questionService.getAllQuestion();        
  }        
  }
```

The **ListQuestionController.java** uses Spring REST temaplate ( generates JSP page ) is as follows:

```
package com.bargadss.SpringService.Controller;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.bargadss.SpringService.Domain.*;

@Controller
public class ListQuestionController {

 @RequestMapping("/listQuestion/{tag1},{tag2},{tag3}")
    public ModelAndView listQuestions(@PathVariable("tag1") String Tag1, @PathVariable("tag2") String Tag2, @PathVariable("tag3") String Tag3) { 
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url="http://localhost:8080/FetchQuestions/service/question/{tag1},{tag2},{tag3}";
        List<LinkedHashMap> Qobj=restTemplate.getForObject(url, List.class,Tag1,Tag2,Tag3);
        return new ModelAndView("listQuestion", "questions", Qobj);
    }

 @RequestMapping("/listAllQuestion/")
    public ModelAndView listAllQuestion() { 
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url="http://localhost:8080/FetchQuestions/service/question/";
        List<LinkedHashMap> Qobj=restTemplate.getForObject(url, List.class);
        return new ModelAndView("listQuestion", "questions", Qobj);
    }

 @RequestMapping("/insertQuestionAnswer/{user_id}/{qtn_id}/{answer}")
    public ModelAndView insertQuestionAnswer(@PathVariable("user_id") String user_ID,
           @PathVariable("qtn_id") String qtn_ID, @PathVariable("answer") String answer) { 
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url="http://localhost:8080/FetchQuestions/service/question/insert/{user_id}/{qtn_id}/{answer}";
        List<LinkedHashMap> Qobj=restTemplate.getForObject(url, List.class,user_ID,qtn_ID,answer);
        return new ModelAndView("listQuestion", "questions", Qobj);
    }

  }
```

The **QuestionService.java** Class performs the DAO activity as Follows :

```
package com.bargadss.SpringService.DAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.bargadss.SpringService.Domain.*;
import com.bargadss.SpringService.Utility.DBUtility;


public class QuestionService {

private Connection connection;

 public QuestionService() {
  connection = DBUtility.getConnection();
 }

 public void insertAnswer(int userId,int qtnId,String answer){
    //Question_Answer objQA = new Question_Answer();
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try{
         preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into question_answer values (?,?,?)");
         preparedStatement.setInt(1, userId);
         preparedStatement.setInt(2, qtnId);
         preparedStatement.setString(3, answer);
         int result = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
         if(result == 0)
            System.out.println("INSERTION OF DATA FAILED");
    } catch (SQLException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try { if (preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close(); } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Exception Closing The Prepared Statement");e.printStackTrace();};
    }
 }

 public List<Questions> getAllQuestion(){
     Questions objQ = new Questions();
     ResultSet rs = null;
     PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
     List<Questions> qtns = new ArrayList<Questions>();
     try {
           preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from questions");             
           rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

           while(rs.next()) {
            objQ.setQuestion_id(Integer.parseInt( rs.getString("Question_id") ) );
            objQ.setQuestion_text(rs.getString("Question_Text"));
            qtns.add(objQ);   
           }
     } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }    
       finally{
           try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Exception Closing The result Set");e.printStackTrace();};
           try { if (preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close(); } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Exception Closing The Prepared Statement");e.printStackTrace();};
           /*try { if (connection != null) connection.close(); } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Exception Closing The Connection");e.printStackTrace();};*/
       }
    return qtns;
 }

 public List<Questions> getQuestionByTag(String Tag1,String Tag2,String Tag3){       
     Questions objQ = new Questions();
     ResultSet rs = null;
     PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
     List<Questions> qtns = new ArrayList<Questions>();
     try {
           preparedStatement = connection.
           prepareStatement("select questions.Question_id,questions.Question_Text from questions,questiontype " +
                            "where questions.Question_id=questiontype.Question_id " +
                            "and questiontype.Tag in (?,?,?)");
           preparedStatement.setString(1, Tag1);
           preparedStatement.setString(2, Tag2);
           preparedStatement.setString(3, Tag3);
           rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

           while(rs.next()) {
            objQ.setQuestion_id(Integer.parseInt( rs.getString("Question_id") ) );
            objQ.setQuestion_text(rs.getString("Question_Text"));
            qtns.add(objQ);   
           }
     } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }    
       finally{
           try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Exception Closing The result Set");e.printStackTrace();};
           try { if (preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close(); } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Exception Closing The Prepared Statement");e.printStackTrace();};
           /*try { if (connection != null) connection.close(); } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Exception Closing The Connection");e.printStackTrace();};*/
       }
    return qtns;
}

}
```

On Execution of The Project *(Apache Tomcat 7.0.12)* with The Following URL it generates **HTTP STATUS 500**

```
http://localhost:8080/FetchQuestions/insertQuestionAnswer/3/9/True
```

Also When I Execute The Following URL it generates **HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported**

```
http://localhost:8080/FetchQuestions/service/question/insert/3/9/True
```

What Am I Doing Wrong ?  Am I Missing Something ?

The Stack Trace For HTTP Status 500 is As Follows :

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [rest] in context with path [/FetchQuestions] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 Method Not Allowed] with root cause
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 Method Not Allowed
>       at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:576)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:532)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:489)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:226)
>       at com.bargadss.SpringService.Controller.ListQuestionController.insertQuestionAnswer(ListQuestionController.java:47)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Did you debug it using break points?

Comment: yes I debuged The Code and Tested It.

Comment: Could you please add the stack trace

Comment: plz share the exception stack trace as well

Comment: Http Status 405 Returns following stack Trace - >Oct 28, 2014 5:23:47 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: Your method addQuestions has RequestMethod.POST ... when you hit the URL from your browser you're sending a GET request, not a POST. If you  access service/question/insert from your browser you have to remove the restriction method=RequestMethod.POST or add explicitly GET requests : method= { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET } too so that it can be hit.Please try it once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also When I Execute The Following URL it generates HTTP Status 405 -
>   Request method 'GET' not supported

Change the request method of `SpringServiceController.SpringServiceController` method from `POST` to `GET`. And it should solve your problem.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/insert/{user_id}/{question_id}/{answer}",method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
```